# Preline javascript file is throwing a 404 for my Astro project

Tags: node.js, tailwind-css, astrojs

I have decided to use the [Preline UI](https://preline.co/) for my Astro project.  I have followed, step by step, their instructions on [installation for Astro](https://preline.co/docs/frameworks-astro.html).  Here is what my tailwind.config.mjs looks like:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}",
        "./node_modules/preline/preline.js",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [require("preline/plugin")],
};
```

---

Here is what my index.astro file looks like:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
        <title>Astro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header
            class="flex flex-wrap sm:justify-start sm:flex-nowrap z-50 w-full bg-white border-b border-gray-200 text-sm py-3 sm:py-0 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700"
        >
            <nav
                class="relative max-w-7xl w-full mx-auto px-4 sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between sm:px-6 lg:px-8"
                aria-label="Global"
            >
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <a
                        class="flex-none text-xl font-semibold dark:text-white"
                        href="#"
                        aria-label="Brand">Brand</a
                    >
                    <div class="sm:hidden">
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            class="hs-collapse-toggle w-9 h-9 flex justify-center items-center text-sm font-semibold rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:text-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
                            data-hs-collapse="#navbar-collapse-with-animation"
                            aria-controls="navbar-collapse-with-animation"
                            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                        >
                            <svg
                                class="hs-collapse-open:hidden w-4 h-4"
                                width="16"
                                height="16"
                                fill="currentColor"
                                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                            >
                                <path
                                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                                    d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"
                                ></path>
                            </svg>
                            <svg
                                class="hs-collapse-open:block flex-shrink-0 hidden w-4 h-4"
                                width="16"
                                height="16"
                                fill="currentColor"
                                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                            >
                                <path
                                    d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"
                                ></path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div
                    id="navbar-collapse-with-animation"
                    class="hs-collapse hidden overflow-hidden transition-all duration-300 basis-full grow sm:block"
                >
                    <div
                        class="flex flex-col gap-y-4 gap-x-0 mt-5 sm:flex-row sm:items-center sm:justify-end sm:gap-y-0 sm:gap-x-7 sm:mt-0 sm:ps-7"
                    >
                        <a
                            class="font-medium text-blue-600 sm:py-6 dark:text-blue-500"
                            href="#"
                            aria-current="page">Landing</a
                        >
                        <a
                            class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-400 sm:py-6 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-gray-500"
                            href="#">Account</a
                        >
                        <a
                            class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-400 sm:py-6 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-gray-500"
                            href="#">Work</a
                        >
                        <a
                            class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-400 sm:py-6 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-gray-500"
                            href="#">Blog</a
                        >

                        <div
                            class="hs-dropdown [--strategy:static] sm:[--strategy:fixed] [--adaptive:none] sm:[--trigger:hover] sm:py-4"
                        >
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                class="flex items-center w-full text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-400 font-medium dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-gray-500"
                            >
                                Dropdown
                                <svg
                                    class="ms-2 w-2.5 h-2.5 text-gray-600"
                                    width="16"
                                    height="16"
                                    viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                                    fill="none"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                >
                                    <path
                                        d="M2 5L8.16086 10.6869C8.35239 10.8637 8.64761 10.8637 8.83914 10.6869L15 5"
                                        stroke="currentColor"
                                        stroke-width="2"
                                        stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </button>

                            <div
                                class="hs-dropdown-menu transition-[opacity,margin] duration-[0.1ms] sm:duration-[150ms] hs-dropdown-open:opacity-100 opacity-0 sm:w-48 hidden z-10 bg-white sm:shadow-md rounded-lg p-2 dark:bg-gray-800 sm:dark:border dark:border-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-700 before:absolute top-full sm:border before:-top-5 before:start-0 before:w-full before:h-5"
                            >
                                <a
                                    class="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-lg text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
                                    href="#"
                                >
                                    About
                                </a>
                                <div
                                    class="hs-dropdown relative [--strategy:static] sm:[--strategy:absolute] [--adaptive:none] sm:[--trigger:hover]"
                                >
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        class="w-full flex justify-between w-full items-center text-sm text-gray-800 rounded-lg py-2 px-3 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
                                    >
                                        Sub Menu
                                        <svg
                                            class="sm:-rotate-90 ms-2 w-2.5 h-2.5 text-gray-600"
                                            width="16"
                                            height="16"
                                            viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                                            fill="none"
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        >
                                            <path
                                                d="M2 5L8.16086 10.6869C8.35239 10.8637 8.64761 10.8637 8.83914 10.6869L15 5"
                                                stroke="currentColor"
                                                stroke-width="2"
                                                stroke-linecap="round"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>

                                    <div
                                        class="hs-dropdown-menu transition-[opacity,margin] duration-[0.1ms] sm:duration-[150ms] hs-dropdown-open:opacity-100 opacity-0 sm:w-48 hidden z-10 sm:mt-2 bg-white sm:shadow-md rounded-lg p-2 dark:bg-gray-800 sm:dark:border dark:border-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-700 before:absolute sm:border before:-end-5 before:top-0 before:h-full before:w-5 top-0 end-full !mx-[10px]"
                                    >
                                        <a
                                            class="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-lg text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
                                            href="#"
                                        >
                                            About
                                        </a>
                                        <a
                                            class="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-lg text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
                                            href="#"
                                        >
                                            Downloads
                                        </a>
                                        <a
                                            class="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-lg text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
                                            href="#"
                                        >
                                            Team Account
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <a
                                    class="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-lg text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
                                    href="#"
                                >
                                    Downloads
                                </a>
                                <a
                                    class="flex items-center gap-x-3.5 py-2 px-3 rounded-lg text-sm text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-300 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
                                    href="#"
                                >
                                    Team Account
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <a
                            class="flex items-center gap-x-2 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-blue-600 sm:border-s sm:border-gray-300 sm:my-6 sm:ps-6 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-blue-500"
                            href="#"
                        >
                            <svg
                                class="flex-shrink-0 w-4 h-4"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                width="16"
                                height="16"
                                fill="currentColor"
                                viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                            >
                                <path
                                    d="M8 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zm4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H3s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C11.516 10.68 10.289 10 8 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10z"
                                ></path>
                            </svg>
                            Log in
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <script is:inline src="./assets/vendor/preline/preline.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

However, I'm getting thrown the following 404 error: `[404] /assets/vendor/preline/preline.js`

---

I'm still not very familiar with Node and projects built with it. I followed the steps exactly, but the actual JS file is under node_modules/preline/preline.js NOT under the public folder. I don't see an assets folder anywhere.

How do I access the files and why is it not working following the instructions step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to link the preline js file as follows:

```
<script>import "preline/dist/preline.js";</script>
```

Just replace the `<script is:inline src="./assets/vendor/preline/preline.js"></script>` with `<script>import "preline/dist/preline.js";</script>` and you should be fine.